# 'ClientRect' is deprecated

Tags: typescript, deprecated

I'm working on some old TypeScript projects made by someone else and they used `ClientRect` like this:

```
type CallbackFn = (rect: ClientRect) => void;
```

TypeScript is saying that 'ClientRect' is deprecated. What is the alternative?

Comment: What _is_ `ClientRect`? It doesn't seem to be [in TypeScript itself](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2FTypeScript%20clientrect&type=code). Typically the [deprecation tag](https://jsdoc.app/tags-deprecated.html) will include information about what to use instead.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Some context (in particular a [mcve] of the code which triggers the deprecation warning, and a description of what you are trying to acheive by using ClientRect) would make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: In the typescript source `lib.dom.d.ts` I see `interface ClientRect extends DOMRect {}`. So you could just use `DOMRect` instead.

Comment: go to typescript>lib>lib.dom.d.ts
at line 5580 

/** @deprecated */
interface ClientRect extends DOMRect {
}

Comment: Why are you using it in the first place? What code do you have that requires an alternative? (`DOMRect` would be the normal go to if you're using `getBoundingClientRect()`)

Comment: oh wow @TmTron you're right.. but why is it deprecated though ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ClientRect* inherits from *DOMRect*, so you can use DOMRect.

```
/** @deprecated */
interface ClientRect extends DOMRect {
}
```

DOMRect:

```
/** [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/DOMRect) */
interface DOMRect extends DOMRectReadOnly {
    height: number;
    width: number;
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
```

Comment: so there is nothing special about ClientRect to have any alternatives ? makes me question why its there in the first place?